# Select the first image of div as an Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to hide the image inside a div, depending on the click count.
How can I select those imgs like an array element?

https://jsfiddle.net/u5mgk3rw/

```
var slider = $('#slides img');
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#change").click(function(){
        slider[clickCount].css("visibility","hidden");
    });   
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set value to counter and increment it. Make sure you do not exceed the `clickCount` by the total count of images.

**[Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/u5mgk3rw/1/)**

```
var slider = $('#slides img');    
clickCount = 0;        
 $("#change").click(function(){     
     if(clickCount < slider.length)
        slider.eq(clickCount++).css("visibility","hidden");
 }) ;
```

If you want to rotate the images then you can set index of first when you reach the last image. I hide all the images and display first with jQuery on `document.load` but this could be done with html.

[Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/u5mgk3rw/2/)

```
var slider = $('#slides img');
slider.hide();
slider.eq(0).show();
clickCount = 0;    
 $("#change").click(function(){
     if(clickCount < slider.length)
           slider.eq(clickCount++).hide();
     if(clickCount == slider.length)
         clickCount = 0;
      slider.eq(clickCount).show();
 }) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to hide the images then use display equals to none, because with visibility you hides the image but it also takes the space on page

```
slider = $('#slides img');    
clickCount = 0;        
$("#change").click(function(){     
   if(clickCount < slider.length)
            slider.eq(clickCount++).css("display","
}) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide the images, not changing visibility then

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var slider = $('#slides img');

  $("#change").click(function() {
    slider.filter(':visible:first').hide()
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="change">hide me</div>

<div id="slides">
  <img class="image" src="http://www.overlandtojapan.com/images/Mongolia%20Background%20Original.jpg" alt="Mountain View">
  <img class="image" src="http://www.tourisminrussia.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/mongolkhans-mongolia.jpg" alt="Mountain View">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wan to **remove** those **image** **one** by **one** than used to this format .

```js
    
 $("#change").click(function(){
    $('#slides img:first-child').remove();
 }) ;
```

```css
#slides img {visibility: visible;width:100px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="change">Remove Image one by one</div>

<div id="slides">
<img  class="image" src="http://www.overlandtojapan.com/images/Mongolia%20Background%20Original.jpg" alt="Mountain View" >
       <img  class="image" src="http://www.tourisminrussia.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/mongolkhans-mongolia.jpg" alt="Mountain View" >
 <img  class="image" src="http://www.tourisminrussia.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/mongolkhans-mongolia.jpg" alt="Mountain View" >
 <img  class="image" src="http://www.tourisminrussia.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/mongolkhans-mongolia.jpg" alt="Mountain View" >
 <img  class="image" src="http://www.tourisminrussia.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/mongolkhans-mongolia.jpg" alt="Mountain View" >
 <img  class="image" src="http://www.tourisminrussia.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/mongolkhans-mongolia.jpg" alt="Mountain View" >
 <img  class="image" src="http://www.tourisminrussia.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/mongolkhans-mongolia.jpg" alt="Mountain View" >
 <img  class="image" src="http://www.tourisminrussia.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/mongolkhans-mongolia.jpg" alt="Mountain View" >
 <img  class="image" src="http://www.tourisminrussia.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/mongolkhans-mongolia.jpg" alt="Mountain View" >
 <img  class="image" src="http://www.tourisminrussia.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/mongolkhans-mongolia.jpg" alt="Mountain View" >
</div>
```